# What is this language? Is it an ancient language?

Tags: historical-linguistics, history, african-languages, ancient

I have recently procured an artefact, which was excavated in Yemen. At the bottom of the artefact there is engraving as shown in the picture. Some of the letters (on two sides) look like Egyptian hieroglyphs, but I am not sure, and I have no idea what the ones in the middle are....

Could someone please help me figure out what this is (and preferably what it means)?

Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a Facebook group just for guessing languages by the way: https://www.facebook.com/groups/guessthelanguage/?fref=ts

Comment: Why did you delete the pictures?

Comment: I am wondering about that too.

Comment: Haven't you already given me the answer? I was trying to close the thread. Isn't it the common way of doing things around here? I am new, so...

Comment: No, you should keep the thread open for the education of future readers and put the picture back.  I often learn things on SE sites from conversations that took place years ago.

Comment: Although language identification is offtopic (hence voted to close), the removal of pictures does not improve the question, it is simply vandalizing the post. Reverted the last, 3-years-old, edit.

Answer (score 7):

Some of these letters are clumsy imitations of Ancient South Arabian script, others are made up. It looks like a fake.

Many years ago I worked as a volunteer at the National Museum in San’a. The storeroom of the museum was full of this sort of thing. The government had the enlightened policy of paying farmers for any “antiquity” they brought in, even if it was obviously fake. The idea was to discourage them from selling authentic antiquities on the private market.

PS. These comments refer to the first picture; the second one was added later.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Do you remember if there were professionals in the museum authenticating those "sort of things"? A friend of mine who is from Yemen was however not satisfied with his government.

Comment: By the way, I just added a picture of another sculpture. Could you please take a look at it as well?

Answer (score 0):

I can read the writing on your second picture. It has (from right to left) the letters ḥqn / mf; I assume there is more writing on the sides and the back. The visible letters do not form complete words.